# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Config\user\User' not found in

Tags: php

Estoy usando `namespace` y `use` en php pero me sale error de:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Config\user\User' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zll\pruebas\src\model\model.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zll\pruebas\src\index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\zll\pruebas\src\model\model.php on line 4
```

El codigo es:

**Archivo de clase** ruta: \config\user.php

```
<?php
namespace Config\user;

class User {
    protected $user = 'Usuario'
    public function name(){
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**Archivo de uso namespace** ruta: \model\model.php

```
<?php
use Config\user\User;

class UserAdmin extends User{
    public functio getUserName(){
        return $this->name."- admin";
    }
}
```

**Archivo de llamada** ruta: \index.php

```
<?php

require_once('./model/model.php');


$name = new UserAdmin();

echo $name->getUserName();
```

Comment: Yo veo que en el archivo `UserAdmin` tratas de usar la clase `User` pero no noto donde invocas a dicho archivo para que pueda *conocer a la clase en cuestión*

Comment: La clase `UserAdmin` debe tener antes del `use` un `require` que solicite al archivo `User` y de este modo pueda funcionar la invocación del namespace que solicitas

Comment: Ahora una duda al margen ¿por qué debería existir una clase `UserAdmin` y por que esta extiende del `User`?, lo digo por que el tipo de usuario podría ser un atributo pero de una clase `Role` tal vez

Comment: En tu ejemplo pones **ruta: \config\user.php**, según tengo entendido en el `namespace` solo tienes que poner la ruta de tus carpetas en donde se encuentra tu clase **User**, es decir, `namespace Config`, y en el `use` debes poner la ruta de carpetas y el nombre de la clase a utilizar, es decir, `use Config\User;`

Comment: Primero tienes que incluir el archivo user.php antes que el model.php

Answer (score 3):

Tienes en tu ejemplo varios errores.

1. Tu warning es porque no encuentra tu clase llamado User, esto es porque no estas usando correctamente los nombres de espacios (namespace) en tus archivos.
2. Escribiste `public functio^^^^ getUserName()` se te olvido la *n*, sería `function`.
3. Luego se te olvido las llaves `()` en `return $this->name` deberia ser `return $this->name()`

Supongamos que mis archivos estén de la siguiente manera;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Posible ejemplo:**

*user.php*

```
<?php 
// Ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo user.php
Namespace Php\Config;

class User {

    protected $user = 'Usuario';

    public function name() {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

*model.php*

```
// Ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo model.php
Namespace Php\Model;

// Incluimos nuestra clase user
require_once 'Php/Config/user.php';

// Importar/apodar un nombre de clase
use Php\Config\User;

// Heredamos tambien la clase User (extends)
class UserAdmin extends User {
    
    public function getUserName() {     

        return $this->name() . " - admin";
    }
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php 

// Incluimos nuestra clase
require_once 'Php/Model/model.php';

// Importar/apodar un nombre de clase
use Php\Model\UserAdmin;    

// Instanciar objeto
$user = new UserAdmin();

// Retornamos valor
echo $user->getUserName();
    
?>
```

Obtendremos en LocalHost:

*Usuario - admin*

### Breve explicacion sobre `namespace`

Un espacio de nombre conocido como `namespace` es un contenedor que nos permite agrupar nuestro código para usarlo posteriormente, y así evitar conflictos de nombres. Por ejemplo, en el caso de tener dos funciones con el mismo nombre, esto genera un error, pero usando los espacios de nombres se solucionan estos conflictos.

Los espacios de nombres pueden agrupar clases, interfaces, funciones y constantes relacionadas.

**Definir un namespace**

Para definir un `namespace` se recomienda siguiendo la ruta de tu carpeta, por ejemplo, has creado una clase llamado `User` en esta `ruta: Php/Config/user.php`entonces mi `namespace` quedaría así:

`Namespace Php\Config;`

**Para hacer uso del namespace**

Cogemos como ejemplo el codigo de arriba

```
// Incluimos nuestra clase
require_once 'Php/Model/model.php';

// Instanciar objeto
$user = new UserAdmin();

// Retornamos valor
echo $user->getUserName();
```

Y obtendremos el siguiente error

> Class 'UserAdmin' not found in...

Porque como mencione los `namespaces` son contenedores para agrupar código, por lo tanto, si queremos hacer uso de la función de la clase UserAdmin debemos llamar al `namespace`.
PHP tiene la palabra reservada `use`, es decir, quedaría así: `use Php\Model\UserAdmin;`

Si quieres invocar varios espacios de nombres a partir de PHP 7 quedaría así:

Supongamos que en la carpeta Model se encuentra la clase *UserAdmin* y *Conexion*, entonces podríamos hacer lo siguiente.

`use Php\Model\{ UserAdmin, Conexion };`

Te dejo también unos enlaces:

[Manual PHP espacio de nombres](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

[Namespaces en PHP](https://anexsoft.com/que-son-y-ejemplo-de-namespaces-en-php)