# ¿Cómo uso los espacios de nombres en PHP?

Tags: php

¡Muy buenas! Estoy empezando a conocer los espacios de nombres en PHP. Según la documentación, con declarar al inicio del fichero "namespace Foo\Bar", en teoría, dentro de cualquier otro fichero PHP, con poner al inicio "use Foo\Bar", esa clase podría usarse. Todo esto lo entiendo, pero a la hora de la implementación, lo único que consigo es un error del tipo: **No se encuentra la clase**

¿Por qué? ¿No se supone que se ha importado con el namespace?

También he visto que hay que poner el **require** en el inicio del fichero para importar la clase, pero, ¿qué pasa en los frameworks? Nunca he visto un require al inicio de un fichero, solo **use**.

¿Alguien puede explicarme por qué pasa esto?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. La mejor forma de explicar tu duda siempre será con un ejemplo mínimo

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Se debe incluir el archivo de la clase, ya sea con `require` o `include`. En los frameworks suelen usarse [funciones de autocarga](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.autoload.php) para evitar que manualmente incluyas esos archivos.

Comment: Aquí te dejo una respuesta, quizás te puede orientar un poco: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424503/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-config-user-user-not-found-in/424752#424752

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.